# Waterline queries with low-level Driver

Tags: orm, sails.js, waterline

We have an application in Sailsjs v1.x where we need to connect to databases dynamically based on a request parameter.
Since datastores cannot achieve this, we tried the method given here by using Drivers: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/driver.

We are using MySQL as our database.

Our question is

1. Is there any way to use Models and Waterline queries with Driver rather than writing Native Queries? We would like to take advantage of the waterline ORM as much as possible.
2. Any other way to use dynamic database connections with Waterline?